# get actual date in unix timestamp and the convert it to gmt-3 in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to get current unix timestamp and then convert it to my local time which is GMT-3, Buenos Aires.

I've done some research but I just can't find a post that fits my problem.

To ask for actual date I do:

```
  $date = new \DateTime();
```

which returns this date object:

```
 object(DateTime)[28]
 public 'date' => string '2015-06-03 11:06:18.000000' (length=26)
 public 'timezone_type' => int 3
 public 'timezone' => string 'America/Buenos_Aires' (length=20)
```

HOw can I access to timezone_type? it gives me error if I do 
    $date->timezone_type

and how can I convert unix timestamp to gmt-3?

Dates are driving me crazy, please help

Answer (score 3):

I hope below example will help you.

```
$day = date('Y-m-d', time());
$date = new DateTime($day, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

example output is

```
2015-06-03 00:00:00+12:00
2015-06-03 01:45:00+13:45
```